# jquery ui sortable receive method revert

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

On a simple jquery ui sortable implementation, if you have `return false` on `receive` event, after you do multiple drags n drop sometimes it randomly reverts the items:

http://jsfiddle.net/neohunter/c14skcb2/1/

Do this:

1) Move one li from ONE to TWO.
2) Move From THREE to one

And the ONE record on TWO moves back to ONE.

Is this a bug? it only happen when the source field got empty aparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is the return value of the receive function. 
The meaning of receive is: This event is triggered when an item from a connected sortable list has been dropped into another list.
So, the correct usage is to set it to true.
Instead to prevent the default behaviour can be useful for event like out:

```
out: function(e, ui) {
if (ui.item.text() == 'One Element') {
    return false;  // prevent all these elements to move
} else {
    return true;
}
```

```js
$( "ul" ).sortable( {
  connectWith: 'ul',
  receive: function(e, ui){
    return true;
  }
});
```

```css
 ul{
            min-height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<h3>One</h3>
<ul>
    <li>One Element</li>
    <li>One Element</li>
    <li>One Element</li>
</ul>

<h3>Two</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Two Element</li>
    <li>Two Element</li>
</ul>

<h3>Three</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Three Element</li>
</ul>
```